# Share Bar over laps left column

Tags: plugins

on my posts page i have a share thing in the side bar, however the side bar over laps the main content even though there is plenty of room on the right, i have tried changing single right column and single left column but nothing makes any difference, any advice would be appreciated.

```
http://79.170.40.241/shaddersafrica.com/?p=119
```

Thanks

Lee

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `#primary` container is only `620px` wide:

```
#primary {
    float: left;
    width: 620px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, i have just changed that to 700px, and i did previously as it was the first thing i tried but it makes no difference.

Comment: You also have this container, that you should widen:
#single-column-left {
float: left;
width: 460px;
background: url(images/bg-widget-title.gif) left top repeat-x;
}

Comment: Thanks I just widend that to 700px but again it hasn't made any diffrence.

Comment: I am not seeing your changes here: http://79.170.40.241/shaddersafrica.com/?p=119

Comment: Thank you, i was adding the file to the wrong folder and didn't even realise, the changes have made a difference, thank you, much appreciated